# Building json response

Tags: c#, json, wcf, rest, self-hosting

I'm working on a self hosting rest api used to monitor de status of several servers.

I was tasked that, when everything is working correctly, I should only return

```
{"response":"ok"}
```

But, when there's an error on queried server, or servers, I must return

```
{  "response" :  [ {"agent":"<server>:<port>","port":"<port>" ,"Error":"<Description of the error>"} ]  }
```

I was thinking on building a helper class to build object on this schema and returning them over the rest api

```
public class HelperErrorResponseClass
{
    public string agent { get; set; }
    public string port { get; set; }
    public string Error { get; set; }
}
```

This is no problem, the issue is, how to deal when everything it ok. I have this Api response helper class

```
public class Response
{
    public string response { get; set; }
}
```

But I'm seeing that I'll need to change the response property to `List<HelperErrorResponseClass>` in order to send the error response. Do you think that, if I stringify the `List<HelperErrorResponseClass>` object with Json.Net it will be returned in the desired format?

Edit: Forgot to add that, I-m using Web Api to build the rest service.

**UDPATE**:

After further research, I found a way to work this out.

Following [this post](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/69146910-241e-4a15-964c-e7f032884b4b/service-returning-object-fails-when-object-is-complex-class?forum=wcf), I was able to rewrite the helper classes like this

```
[DataContract]
[KnownType(typeof(List<HelperErrorResponseClass>))]
public class Response
{
    [DataMember]
    public object response { get; set; }
}

[DataContract]
public class HelperErrorResponseClass
{
    [DataMember(EmitDefaultValue = false)]
    public string agent { get; set; }
    [DataMember(EmitDefaultValue = false)]
    public string port { get; set; }
    [DataMember(EmitDefaultValue = false)]
    public string error { get; set; }
}
```

This work to fulfill my and my client needs... except for one little thing. When I get the result from a List, and given that I added the `KnownTypes` directive, my response is now this

```
{"response":[{"__type":"HelperErrorResponseClass:#AppCommonLib","Error":"ERROR","InstanceId":"<InstanceId> : <Port>","PortType":"<PortType>"},{"__type":"HelperErrorResponseClass:#AppCommonLib","Error":"ERROR","InstanceId":"<InstanceId> : <Port>","PortType":"<PortType>"}]}
```

Any idea how to get rid of that `__type` property of the response? make that it must be explicit to only return the declared properties of the helper class?

Comment: I haven't used Json.Net library, but it should be able to stringify the list properly. What don't you give it a try and see? I use ServiceStack.Text and it does the job perfectly.

Comment: @RacilHilan wil give it a try. I posted this minutes before I was out of the office and wanted to know your opinions first thing comming into

Answer (score 1):

Simplest way to deal with this is to set the return type on the handling function to string, then you can check for errors and do something like;

```
//pseudo code to give an idea
if (errorsList.Count() > 0)
{
     return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(errorsList);
}
else
{
     return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new Response("ok"));
}
```

Now this being said... Unless the people providing requirements aren't at all flexible you should just redo the design. How about just returning the errors array and the person calling the API can infer that if it's length is 0 then everything is working OK. Seems pretty straight forward, right? You could also just put all the properties on one object and those fields would just come back as null or empty strings. Or you could change you serializer settings to exclude them if they don't have a value.

Comment: Just as you said it, they aren't that flexible and its the way they want it, but I'm working with them on a way to work it out

Answer (score 1):

Keep things simple and use an anonymous type.

```
if (condition) 
{
    return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new { response = new { agent = "x", port = "y", error = "z" }});
}
else 
{
   return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new { response = "ok"});  
}
```

More info:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397696.aspx

Comment: yeah, I forgot about anonymous types, will give it a try!

Comment: It kinda worked, but now, I'm facing that, once I return the serialized json string string, its begin serialized once again on the response of the request, ending up with `"{\"response\":\"OK\"}"` adding several backslashes and and extra quotes, its serializing to json the json string, xD

Comment: MVC?  WebApi?  What technology are you using?

Comment: Anonymous types are a _terrific_ way to eff up a contract and give yourself a lot of headaches later on. WebApi maybe, but avoid it in WCF.

Comment: --You're right, Brad.  I assumed WebAPI or MVC.  WCF, no way!

Comment: @BradChristie I already tried MVC and Web Api, and didn't play nicely with my self hosted app, besides, they didn't work on the deployment server because they missed some libraries required to run, and, guess what.... I'm not allowed to install anything on those, as they are, must have the app deployed, :(

Comment: @CJLpoez Personally, I'd have a `Response` base object, deviated with known type of the two other response types: `OkResponse` & `BadResponse`. From there you can have the contact setup to use `Response`, but have the ability to return either.

Comment: Now your contract is satisfied, you have strong types, and fulfill the requirement. And serialization will happen as expected.

Answer (score 1):

I personally don't think you need a `Response` class, especially that it is of `object` type. IMHO, you've overcomplicated the very simple issue that you have. It is not only the `__type`, but also other info like `HelperErrorResponseClass:#AppCommonLib` that isn't supposed to be there.

Another Issue you have is the incorrect name of the `HelperErrorResponseClass` class. This is not a helper class. It is a standard data-object class.

> A helper class is a class filled with static methods.  It is usually used to isolate a "useful" algorithm.

This is how I would do it:

1. I'd get rid of the `Response` class.
2. I'd use your original simple `HelperErrorResponseClass` class, but rename it to something more meaningful like `ErrorDetails`.
3. I'd return the response like this:

.

```
if (errorsList.Count() > 0) {
    return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new { response = errorsList});
}
else {
   return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new { response = "ok"});
}
```

However, if you really want to stick to your updated solution, an easy way to get rid of the `__type` is simply removing it from the final serialized string:

```
if (errorsList.Count() > 0) {
    string r = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new { response = errorsList});
    return r.Replace("__type", "");
}
else {
   return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new { response = "ok"});
}
```

Comment: This is a good solution, but the problem is, given that I'm using WCF, the response, which its already a json string of the object, its parsed to jason, once again.

So, instead of getting `{"response":"ok"}` I'm getting `"{\"response\":\"ok\"}"` so, using `JsonConvert.SerializeObject` its not a good option

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you said. Could you post the relevant code? Where are you getting `"{\"response\":\"ok\"}"`? I recommended getting rid of the `response` class. Why your `response` object is already JSON string? Where was it serialized? Then you can simply `return response;`, but I have a feeling that there are issues in other parts of your code.

Comment: I'm using WCF services, returning JSON messages with BARE response body. Given that the method its already returning a json string using the `JsonConvert.SerializeObject`, the service serializes, once again, the returned string of the method, to JSON, adding those backslashes to scape the quotes so, if I grab the response of the service, I do get the json string, instead of the object I need with the property `response` with it's value `"ok"`

Comment: Yeah, that's what I thought. The design is not right. You should only be serializing the object immediately before sending them back to the client. Serialising the response and then do more processing on it is not the way to go. You either need to do the final processing in the WCF itself, or the WCF needs to return the object un-serialized to your final processing code. Well, unless your WCF is sitting on a different server or something. Anyway, I could be wrong since I don't see the code and design. Have you tried the `Replace()` function to get rid of the `__type`?

Comment: The `__type` only appears if I return the `response` object setting the `KnownType` for it to work. If I serialize using the `JsonConverter.SerializeObject` the `__type` never appears so I don't need to use the `replace`

Comment: I know, but you said **using `JsonConvert.SerializeObject` its not a good option**, so I assumed that you're returning the already-serialized response object with the `KnownType`. In this case, I was suggesting that you use the `Replace()` function to get rid of the `__type` as you requested in your updated question. That should work for you because the serialized response is a string.